# how to loop through response from HTTP request in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, http, dart

Here is how I do the request :

```dart
              http.get(Uri.parse("${Constants.BASE_URL}categories/SubWithSubSub/${itemModel.id}"), headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'lang': Constants.LANG
              }).then((secondResponse) async {
                for (var item in secondResponse.body){ //error in this line
                  print(item);
                }
              });
```

and here is how my response looks like :

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":149,"name":"Honey","subSub":{"viewAll":false,"data":[]}},{"id":150,"name":"Herbs","subSub":{"viewAll":false,"data":[]}}]}
```

I see this error :

```
The type 'String' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

I guesse you're fogetting to decode the string which comes in the response body

try this

```
var responseList = jsonDecode(secondResponse.body);
for (var item in responseList ){ //error in this line
              print(item);
            }
```